# Less than a month left on national type D visa from Malta. Can I still enter the Schengen area?

Tags: visas, schengen, multiple-entry

I was issued a 1-year multiple-entry national type D visa for Malta, and now I have less than a month left before it expires. A month ago, I entered another Schengen state with this visa for a 3-day trip. Since I have less than a month left on the visa, and I have already entered another Schengen state, am I still eligible to travel to other Schengen states?

Comment: I don't understand why you're asking this question.  Why wouldn't you be able to travel to another Schengen country?

Comment: I asked the question as I was confused regarding staying in other schengen states for "up to 3 months within a 6 month period" clause - I wasn't entirely sure if traveling to other schengen states on a national D visa was a one time thing or if I could enter other schengen states multiple times as long as I don't exceed the 3 month maximum within any 6 month period. Plus I have less than a month left on my national D visa hence wanted to clarify

Comment: Your visa is valid until the very last day of its validity period. It's not clear why you emphasize that you have less thatn a month left.

Comment: You can stay in the country that issued the D visa for its entire validity period. The 90/180 rule applies to your travel to any other Schengen country using that D visa.